# Gradient of generalized logarithm

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

From Boyd and Vandenberghe Chapter 11; a generalized logarithm $\psi$ for a proper cone $K$ is any function that satisfies these two properties. 1) $\nabla^2 \psi(y) \prec 0$ for any $y \in K$, and 2) for a constant $s > 0$ and all $y \succ_K 0$: $\psi(sy) = \psi(y) + \theta \log y$, where $\theta$ is the degree of $\psi$.

The text then goes on to say that generalized logarithm satisfies the following property: $\nabla \psi(y) \succ_{K^*} 0$ (i.e., the gradient of the generalized log is contained in the dual cone).

How do I prove the above? Are there any references for the above property? I have looked in Rockafellar.

Comment: Does the gradient inequality for $-\psi$ help?

Comment: @AlexShtof What do you mean? Do you mean the following: $y^T \nabla \psi(y) = \theta$ ?

Comment: $-\phi$ is convex because of the hessian. And any differentiable convex function satisfies the gradient inequality $f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (y-x)$.

Comment: Aah I see, that is the first order condition of convexity. Thats a good suggestion. Using that, and the fact $x^T \nabla \psi(x) = \theta $ that you can get: $y^T \nabla \psi(x) \geq \psi(y) - \psi(x) + \theta$. The right hand side (RHS) can be negative. To prove that $\nabla \psi(x) \in K^*$ you need tht RHS to be at least 0 for all $y \in K$.